# Spark Dataset show: Unable to Capture Output Multiple Times

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am asking this question even though I have already got a work around (see answers), to save anyone else this same pain.

I required a method to show my dataset to my log4j logger. I did this using:
`void org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(int numRows, boolean truncate)`
which simply logs to the stdOut. In order to capture the stdOut I did the following (inspiration found somewhere else on stackoverflow):

```
void myMethod(Dataset<Row> data){
    // Save the old System.out
    PrintStream originalPrintStream = System.out;

    // Tell Java to use your special stream
    ByteArrayOutputStream logCollection = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintStream printStreamForCollectingLogs = new PrintStream(logCollection);
    System.setOut(printStreamForCollectingLogs);

    // Print some output: goes to your special stream
    data.show(MAX_DISPLAY_ROWS, false);

    // Put things back
    System.out.flush();
    System.setOut(originalPrintStream);

    logger.info("\n"+logCollection.toString());
    logCollection.reset();
}
```

This works only once, subsequent calls to the same method for the same dataset will fail to capture anything.
I am using:

```
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been caused by the Dataset retaining the byte stream that it first encounters as stdOut, as I was able to resolve this issue by extracting my alternative stdOut stream as a class variable:

```
private static ByteArrayOutputStream logCollection = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
private static PrintStream printStreamForCollectingLogs = new PrintStream(logCollection);
```

This means I am using the same bytestream in `logger.info("\n"+logCollection.toString())` each time. This allows me to call myMethod as often as I want and capture the output each time.